# dompdf dont load bootstrap css with barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i use barryvdh/laravel-dompdf in laravel 5.5 and bootstrap css (renamed to pdf.css with small adjustments) to generate a report in pdf
this is my header from the report view calling the css:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>  
     <link href="{{public_path('css/pdf.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />            
</head>
<body>
```

my controller:

```
 public function infor(News $news)
    {   

        ...     
        PDF::setOptions(['dpi' => 150, 'defaultFont' => 'sans-serif']);         
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.news_events.pdf');            
        return $pdf->stream('pdfview.pdf');
   
}
```

Expected view (html5):
[image]

view generated in pdf :,(
[image]
How could I solve this?

Comment: are you using bootstrap css?

Comment: yes bootstrap 3

Comment: I recommend mPDF. Still not as fancy as I'd like, but better.

Comment: @parker_codes I don't think they're looking for an alternative, but rather a solution

Answer (score 2):

[barryvdh/laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) does not support boostrap yet.

Quoting the author:

> I highly doubt that DomPDF can handle Bootstrap correctly.
>   If you need better pdf, try: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy
>   That used Webkit to render pdf.

See more about the issue [here](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/70)

Comment: How can I use bootstrap grid system with this barryvdh/laravel-dompdf package?

Comment: You can't @Sanjaya

Comment: [Better try snappy](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/70#issuecomment-62137324)

Comment: there are many other alterntives out there, I don't think the author is asking for alternatives to DOMPDF, but rather a solution to an existing problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put all css file in style tag to launch your code

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, all I did was create another blade file, copied bootstrap.css contents into it (between style tags) , then included it (the file with the css) in the file I wanted to print

Answer (score 0):

Change your file path to this, if CSS and images are not inside the public directory.

```
<img src="{{ base_path().'/location/to/image/image.png' }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ base_path().'/location/css/bootstrap.min.css' }}">
```

Comment: This solution not working :(

Answer (score 0):

You should use another version of bootstrap. because i tested it with bootstrap 3 and it's not working but it works with version 4 of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `isHtml5ParserEnabled` option to `true`:

```
PDF::setOptions(['dpi' => 150, 'isHtml5ParserEnabled' => true, 'defaultFont' => 'sans-serif']);
```

This will enable HTML5 parser (disabled by default in the package).

Comment: This solution not working :(