# Bootstrap version compatible with DomPDF Laravel

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, dompdf, laravel-dompdf

i have a question, after i tried many version of bootstrap to use in dompdf laravel, there's no one can compatible. I've searching in other people same question as me, they said bootstrap 3.3.6 is compatible for dompdf laravel. But after i tried, it's not compatible too. Did anyone has solution maybe which bootstrap version compatible with dompdf laravel?

Note: i'm using laravel 8 and PHP 7.4

i've tried to using many bootstrap version but no one is compatible when i generate view into pdf

[image: HTML]

Comment: I recommend using wkhtmltopdf, (laravel package [Laravel Snappy](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy)). Or you can copy the complete minified bootstrap CSS to another blade and include that in the header. That might work for dompdf.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dompdf dont load bootstrap css with barryvdh/laravel-dompdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48760296/dompdf-dont-load-bootstrap-css-with-barryvdh-laravel-dompdf)

Comment: @AnujShrestha so is it no one bootstrap version compatible with dompdf?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 also works with DomPdf but it does not support Flexbox.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35430077)